# JavaScript format array of objects into nested children

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects with parentId and sort values that I'd like to put into an array with nested 'children' and sorted appropriately.

For example, here's the data:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    sort: 2,
    parentId: null,
    name: 'A'
}, {
    id: 2,
    sort: 1,
    parentId: 1,
    name: 'A.1'
}, {
    id: 3
    sort: 2,
    parentId: 1,
    name: 'A.2'
}, {
    id: 4,
    sort: 1,
    parentId: null,
    name: 'B'
}]
```

The way I'd like to transform this would be such as:

```
[{
    id: 4,
    sort: 1,
    parentId: null,
    name: 'B',
    children: []
}, {
    id: 1,
    sort: 2,
    parentId: null,
    name: 'A',
    children: [{
        id: 2,
        sort: 1,
        parentId: 1,
        name: 'A.1'
    }, {
        id: 3
        sort: 2,
        parentId: 1,
        name: 'A.2'
    }]
}]
```

This is sorted (id 4 being at the top, since sort is 1) and the children are nested and also sorted accordingly.

Any suggestions on a good way to do this? I can recursively loop through to apply children, but not sure how I can maintain sorting on this.

Comment: Are the `name`s one character long only? Is the first part of the `name` only alphabets as in `A-Z` or are there numbers and special characters?

Comment: @stackErr I think names do not matter at all here, you don't need them to answer the question. He added those for us to see more easily where everything should go.

Comment: @stackErr yeah the names are just for simplicity sake of the example.  All logic would be based off id, parentId and sort.

Comment: are there endless levels? or only as deep as two?

Comment: There's only two, but probably it should support any level via recursion

Comment: this is tricky, cause you'll have to have the parents available before the children (think of a situation where an object has parentId that is only introduced later)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a proposal which sorts first and filters after that.

The sorting takes the properties `parentId` and `sort`. This is necessary for the next step, because the "filtering" needs a sorted array.

Later the array is filterd with [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), Here is `thisArgs` used for referencing nodes for a possible insertation of children.

Edit: Update for unsorted (`id`/`parentId`) data.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, sort: 2, parentId: null, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, sort: 1, parentId: 1, name: 'A.1' }, { id: 3, sort: 2, parentId: 1, name: 'A.2' }, { id: 4, sort: 1, parentId: null, name: 'B' }],
    nested;

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.parentId || -1) - (b.parentId || -1) || a.sort - b.sort;
});

nested = array.filter(function (a) {
    a.children = this[a.id] && this[a.id].children;
    this[a.id] = a;
    if (a.parentId === null) {
        return true;
    }
    this[a.parentId] = this[a.parentId] || {};
    this[a.parentId].children = this[a.parentId].children || [];
    this[a.parentId].children.push(a);
}, Object.create(null));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(nested, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This doesn't always work, because it uses the `parentId` to sort the data, which is irrelevant. Try it with : `[{id: 1, parentId: null, sort: 1}, {id: 2, parentId: 3, sort: 1}, {id: 3, parentId: 2, sort: 1}]` and you'll find yourself with an exception. Other than that, the `thisArg` trick on `filter` is really nice.

Comment: your data is not valid. it has a circular reference. 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes sorry, here's a better example: `[{id: 1, parentId: 4, sort: 1}, {id: 2, parentId: 3, sort: 1}, {id: 3, parentId: 1, sort: 1}, {id: 4, parentId: null, sort: 1}]`

Comment: @VonD, please see edit, it should work now with (kind of) unsorted data.

Answer (score 2):

I gave it a try and came back, and there are already other answers, but I'm posting it anyway.

This method modifies the original Array:

```js
var items = [{id: 1,sort: 2,parentId: null,name: 'A'}, {id: 2,sort: 1,parentId: 1,name: 'A.1'}, {id: 3,sort: 2,parentId: 1,name: 'A.2'}, {id: 4,sort: 1,parentId: null,name: 'B'}];


function generate_tree(arr){
  var references = {};
  arr.sort(function(a,b){
    // Save references to each item by id while sorting
    references[a.id] = a; references[b.id] = b;
    // Add a children property
    a.children = []; b.children = [];
    if(a.sort > b.sort) return 1;
    if(a.sort < b.sort) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var item = arr[i];
    if(item.parentId !== null && references.hasOwnProperty(item.parentId)){
      references[item.parentId].children.push(arr.splice(i,1)[0]);
      i--; // Because the current index now contains the next item
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(generate_tree(items), null, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd create a new data structure, to look like:

   { 1: {
       id: 1,
       sort: 2,
       parentId: null,
       name: 'A'
    }, 
     2: {
       id: 4,
       sort: 1,
       parentId: null,
       name: 'B'
    }
   }

Things to notice: the new structure **is an object**, not an array, that contains only the topmost elements in it (the ones with `parentId` `null`)

2. Then, do a `for` over the original array, and assign `new_obj[ orig_arr_curr_elem[parentId] ].children.push(orig_arr_curr_elem)`
3. Then create a new array with the elems from `new_obj` `sort()` the  (or the `children` property) however you want

Code that implements the steps 1 and 2 (run this using node):

```
var util = require('util');
var old_arr = [{
    id: 1,
    sort: 2,
    parentId: null,
    name: 'A'
}, {
    id: 2,
    sort: 1,
    parentId: 1,
    name: 'A.1'
}, {
    id: 3,
    sort: 2,
    parentId: 1,
    name: 'A.2'
}, {
    id: 4,
    sort: 1,
    parentId: null,
    name: 'B'
}];

var new_obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < old_arr.length; i++){
    if ( old_arr[i].parentId == null )
        new_obj[ old_arr[i].id ] = old_arr[i];
}

for (var i = 0; i < old_arr.length; i++){
    if ( old_arr[i].parentId == null ) continue;
    new_obj[ old_arr[i].parentId ].children = new_obj[ old_arr[i].parentId ].children || [];
    new_obj[ old_arr[i].parentId ].children.push( old_arr[i] );
}

console.log(util.inspect(new_obj, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
```